# Cannot connect to an email server from a home Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, email, dns, firewall, imap

First off, I'm not entirely sure this is the right Stack page to post this into, but hopefully, I'll be redirected to the proper page if not.

A friend of mine had problems connecting to an email server (her own domain) from her wi-fi. The fact is, with her mac, she can connect to the server and see her emails while on a hotspot from her smartphone, and she asked me for help.

I immediately thought the problem was DNS, and when I ran `nslookup her.domain.server`, she couldn't connect to it from her wi-fi. I changed the DNS server from her wi-fi to google DNS and nslookup was working fine after that, but the problem persisted. Now the IMAP/POP shows that it cannot connect while on the wi-fi, but it can over hotspots and in my home wi-fi, for example.

I'm thinking about firewall rules, but I'm not sure how to test this and how to make it work, since it seems that it's the router that is blocking those requests.

Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: By mac, I meant her computer (Macbook)

Connection can be made, pings and nslookup work, just can't get the connection to her email server (in a domain she bought)

EDIT2: I thought about something else too. Her house is somewhat 'smart', due to her father enjoying that kind of stuff. Maybe the firewall idea was right all along and the port is being blocked by some other service.

At some point i'll check that out and leave a comment here

Comment: What do you mean by "her own domain" exactly ? Have you tried to `ping` the server ? It's hard to understand because you eventually say "with her mac, she can connect to the server". So what's the problem ?

Comment: I wonder if its the ISP - some block mail as a 'anti spam measure' - bit tricky to confirm  unless she has some flavour of webmail, also - do you have access to mail logs?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I should have access to the logs if I access the server. But, since it works fine with some networks and not with her home network, I don't really think the server is actually getting the requests. I don't work with macbooks but at some point I managed to see a panel with all the requests that were made by the email app she has. All the gmails were fine, but the emails that were configured as POP3 or IMAP were not working on her Home Wi-fi

Comment: Erf. Could try connecting via telnet to confirm it fails. https://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/ try the troubleshooting guide there with the localhost ip swapped for your server. It's a rather low level check

Comment: her email is hosted outside of her LAN?

Comment: Yes, @Yorik, it is hosted outside of her lan